# Pycryptodome official example

Tags: python, pycryptodome

I am trying to change an official example from
https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/examples.html

and adapt to a little encryption project I am working on:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP

file_in = open("encrypted_data.bin", "rb")

private_key = RSA.import_key(open("private.pem").read())

enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = \
   [ file_in.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1) ]
```

in my case file from example **encrypted_data.bin** (file_in = open("encrypted_data.bin", "rb")) will be a string variable rather than file.

How to adapt below loop to use string variable instead **file_in** ?

```
enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = \
   [ **file_in.read(x)** for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the file read commands with strings. For example:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP

encrypted_data = "my_data_str"

private_key = RSA.import_key("my_private_key_str")

enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = \
   [ encrypted_data  for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1) ]
```